# JQuery FireFox click event

Tags: jquery, firefox, click

I'm currently struggling with the following Jquery Code in Firefox. 
My goal is to reload a img src path when the image is clicked on.

HTML 5

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="image"><img src="image/image1.jpg" alt="ein smiley" /></a>
```

JQuery (latest version)

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('#image').click(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('img', this).attr('src', 'image/image2.jpg');

    });
});
```

This code works just fine in Internet Explorer 10 and Google Chrome 30.
It doesn't work in FireFox though. I've read that FireFox interprets the click as a form submit. Unfortunately the solution in that thread is quite limited and since I'm not really a JQuery/Javascript expert i can't come to a solution myself with that information.

You can take a look at the original Website here: http://user.enterpriselab.ch/~tajoesle/ajax.php

Would one of you be so nice and help me out here?

Many Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Why did you edit out the `event.preventDefault();` from your code?

Comment: I posted an answer but after testing your code in my firefox, it replaces the src url fine. What error are you getting?

Comment: Well..you have `event` as the parameter but you're calling `e.preventDefault()` -- could that be it?

Comment: @J09691 sorry that was a mistake by me. Put it in again.

Comment: @tymeJV - think that's just a typo. If you look at the edit history of this question you'll see it was in there correctly originally.

Comment: I [**made a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vsUrL/) and tested your code in Firefox; it's working just fine for me. What version of Firefox is it?

Comment: Yes typo by me. Sorry. Fixed it again. FireFox Version is 25.0. Just monitored the Script with Firebug Console. Console stays empty. Absolutely nothing happens in the console. As if it didn't run the script. I have another .click Jquery Function that gets called at another place on my website - doesn't work either :/

Added also the Link to the original webpage in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In provided demo url, may be the reason

http://user.enterpriselab.ch/~tajoesle/ajax.php

I found the 404 error for following js files

```
    <script src="script\jquery.cookie.js\jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="script\style.switch\style.switch.js"></script>
    <script src="script\image.switch\image.switch.js"></script>
```

but it should be

```
    <script src="script/jquery.cookie.js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="script/style.switch/style.switch.js"></script>
    <script src="script/image.switch/image.switch.js"></script>
```

Comment: Augh, beat me to it. Yes, you need to switch from forward slashes to backslashes.

Comment: Chinnu R, u are my Hero of the day. Apparently FireFox doesn't like the backslashes. Every other browser at least accepts them.
Also a big thank you to the others who contributed to the Solution.